# Differences between run R script from command line and in R package

Tags: r, encoding, command-line, utf-8, r-package

When I was using R script with polish letter in RStudio, there was no problem with finding polish symbol (e.g. "ł") with using command gsub. When I used the same script lauching it from command line from Windows 10, command gsub couldn't find symbol "ł". Where could be the problem? Is it maybe different encoding? I used in R script option(encoding="utf-8"). I use polish diactrictics symbols in command line without problem. Is somewhere hidden encoding in cmd?

Comment: To make sure  the file encoding is right you can save your script in RStudio via `File > Save with Encoding...`. Could you try that selecting UTF-8?

Comment: I had written file in encoding 1250, and It started working, so thanks that you pointed me solution